# Count the distinct value by row by group

Tags: r, group-by, distinct

I wish to calculate the unique values by row by group in r .The unique value by row should not include the blank cell.
for e.g,

```
df<-data.frame(
  Group=c("A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","B1","B1","B1"),
  Segment=c("A",NA,"A","B","A",NA,"A","B")
)
```

INPUT:

```
 
+---------+--------+
| Group   |Segment |
+---------+--------+
| A1      |A       |
| A1      |NA      |
| A1      |A       |
| A1      |B       |
| A1      |A       |
| B1      |NA      |
| B1      |A       |
| B1      |B       |
+---------+--------+
```

I have used for loop in solving the problem but in the big dataset it is taking more time in getting the result.

Expected output in **Distinct** column

```
 
+---------+--------+----------+
| Group   |Segment | distinct |
+---------+--------+----------+
| A1      |A       |    1     |
| A1      |NA      |    1     |
| A1      |A       |    1     |
| A1      |B       |    2     |
| A1      |A       |    2     |
| B1      |NA      |    0     |
| B1      |A       |    1     |
| B1      |B       |    1     |
+---------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question? What are expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: Why is the ordering different in the two data.frames?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the expected output also. the requirement is to calculate rowwise unique value by Group (A1/B1) by ignore blank cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`duplicated` is useful for this, although the NAs make it a bit tricky:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(distinct = cumsum(!duplicated(Segment) & !is.na(Segment)))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 8 x 3
> # Groups:   Group [2]
>   Group Segment distinct
>   <fct> <fct>      <int>
> 1 A1    A              1
> 2 A1    NA             1
> 3 A1    A              1
> 4 A1    B              2
> 5 A1    A              2
> 6 B1    NA             0
> 7 B1    A              1
> 8 B1    B              2
> ```

Comment: In base it could be done like: `df$distinct <- ave(unclass(df$Segment), df$Group, FUN=function(x) {cumsum(!duplicated(x) & !is.na(x))})`